# Logstash sincedb file empty and file not read

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using Logstash 7.4.2.
I am trying to read a file as an input and output the line to standard output.
the configuration file is as follows

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:\IMP\Courses\Logstash+Filebeat\logs-trial-1\test"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
output {
    stdout {
    }
}
```

When I start Logstash using this config file, sincedb file is created but with no content, no data is read from the file. What might be the solution to this?

Comment: Try to use forward slashes `/` in your path.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks a lot, it worked !